# mongoose update with push operations on array and set operation on object

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema

```
var ContactSchema = module.exports = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  messages: [
  {
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    msg: {type: String, required: true}
  }],
  address:{ city:String,
            state:String
  }
});
```

I have initially the collection set with name and phone field. I need to update the collection with new messages into messages array and new address into address object. the function must also need to handle any single operation, ie in some case i have only update to messages array or updates to both name and address. so how i can i do all operations in a single function.

```
        var messages= {
            title: req.body.title,
            msg: req.body.msg
        }
        Model.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': req.body.id,},{$push: {messages:message}},{upsert: true}, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            if (!data) {
                return res.status(404).end();
            }
            return res.status(200).send(data);
        });
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: currently i have done the same using different update and post function.

Comment: If you can at least edit your question and include the bits that you have done thus far that would be great.

Comment: updated question. this is what i have done so far

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could try use both the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) and [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operators in your update object. Suppose, for example, you want to update both name and address fields in one single operation, use the `$set` on the name field and a `$push` operation to the address array:

```
var messages= {
    title: req.body.title,
    msg: req.body.msg
},
query = {'_id': req.body.id},
update = {
    $set: {name: req.body.name},
    $push: {messages: message}
},
options = {upsert: true};

Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    if (!data) {
        return res.status(404).end();
    }
    return res.status(200).send(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. how can i handle push for new values and update for existing values in messages array with the same function?